# FullCalendar Not Displaying Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on a simple cms app but I can't get the Full Calendar plugin to display the calendar. I've followed the steps that I found online and nothing has worked. I've been trying to solve this problem for a week and can't figure it out. I've checked the console for errors and it looks good.

So I wanted to reach out. My app is built in PHP, my code is included below. I've linked to everything and the jquery is working.

The code for the calendar I've included in the head section.

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin-main.css">

<title>CMS</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        weekends: true
    });

});
</script>

</head>
```

In the HTML on the calendar page I have this included.

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Lol, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/ozeuoLtp/9/  - it's working with everything exactly as you have above.

Comment: Huh. Ok well that's good to know. Thanks! For some reason it doesn't display on my xampp server. Weird. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `)` on `.fullCalendar()`, should be:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //options
});
```

Example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: true
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Syden! Thanks for letting me know that. I will try to fix this first thing tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hey Snyden, I tried that but now the console is telling me this.

Comment: Hey Syden, I tried that but now the console has errors and is telling me that fullCalendar is not a function. Any ideas? I added your cdn's to the head section and it's still not displaying anything.

Comment: please share a screenshot of your head, sounds like script order issue. Make sure css is first, second jquery, third moment, 4th fullcalendar js.

Comment: <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

Comment: You need to set the full http:// address on src, copy exactly like the snippet above. Scripts aren't being loaded that way. Example: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried that and it's not working. I don't know where the problem is. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: My friend, you have a working example right in front of you! You must be doing something wrong on which I have no control, make sure everything is like on that example otherwise there isn't much I can do. If you update your code I'll try to check it but at this point it's clear the example provided works perfect.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree. It should be working. I'll keep trying. Thank you.

Comment: I just updated my code above with the updated head section. The console tells me that fullCalendar is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and you may have already found the solution, however, i will give my answer to help anyone else that may be running into the same issue.

I found that when the console is giving you the error that fullcalendar is not a function and your code seems to be correct, its for the following reason.

If you are using bootstrap, you need to remove the Jquery link provided in the bootstrap starter template. You have already loaded jquery in the header, by doing it again in the body, it is creating the error.. I hope it helps!